# Import Oracle schema with SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, import, database-schema

I exported a database schema from one server using SQL Developer (Tools-> Database Export). It generated a script, but I have problems executing it on another server.

The schema has a number of triggers/procedures and I got an error (`ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`) creating the first multi-statement trigger(or sp). It works properly if I execute each `CREATE TRIGGER` separately, but it's quite a tedious process ...

I believe it is because of the semicolon between statements in the trigger body, but I don't know how to make it work. What is the right way to execute the script?

**[UPDATE]**
Just in case if someone else has a similar problem, don't forget to switch to a newly created schema `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=NEW_SCHEMA_NAME;` in the beginning of import script.

Comment: Post some of your SQL code and we'll probably be able to help you more.

Comment: Nm, I found the problem ; my bad - I didn't realize that I had to issue `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=NEW_SCHEMA_NAME;` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Please add your answer as a real answer below. Then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case if someone else has a similar problem, don't forget to switch to a newly created schema ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=NEW_SCHEMA_NAME; in the beginning of import script.